# Import Elm front-end from github into Phoenix back-end

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elm

My team is working on a phoenix/elm application, and have decided to keep the two projects in separate repos, and to 'point' to the elm application from the phoenix app. This is sort of new terrain for me, and I've been looking into different ways to accomplish this. I've tried importing the Elm app as a dependency via package.json, but I believe node_modules/ doesn't recognize Elm code. I've also tried importing it as a dependency via mix.exs, but again deps/ it looking for a exs file. Are there any other approaches to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using git, you may want use [git submodules](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for this. It allows you to embed a separate repository within an existing one.

So you could essentially have your Phoenix app as normal, include the Elm app as a submodule, then in your `brunch-config.js`, reference the Elm app via the [elm-brunch](https://github.com/madsflensted/elm-brunch) plugin.

```
elmBrunch: {
  mainModules: ['../path/to/submodule/Main.elm'],
  outputFolder: 'web/static/js/',
  makeParameters: ['--debug']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Phoenix ships with [Brunch](http://brunch.io/) as the asset manager. I have successfully used Brunch to compile my Elm code into a JS package. I can then import that JS into my Phoenix HTML templates and place the Elm application using the [standard method](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html).

I recently wrote a [blog post on putting the pieces together](https://becoming-functional.com/bootstrapping-an-phoenix-elm-project-b6df18312904). This post includes a pointer to a [github repo](https://github.com/billperegoy/phoenix_elm_quickstart) with an example. I'm hoping this will help with the issues you are running into.

The main difference with my approach is that I have the Elm and Phoenix code in the same repo, but I think you can make brunch work as long as you can define a consistent relative path from the Phoenix repo to the Elm repo.

Comment: Thanks! I understand how to embed an elm application in a phoenix app with brunch, the question is how to separate them into different repos. Could you explain what you mean here: "define a consistent relative path from the Phoenix repo to the Elm repo"?

Comment: The brunch config requires you to specify a path to your Elm repo with declarations like this:

elmFolder: 'elm',

I'm thinking that you can probably clone both your elm and phoenix repos into the same parent directory and then use a relative path to point to the elm repo from the Phoenix repo. Maybe:

elmFolder: '../<elm-project>'

I haven't actually tried this yet. I ended up combining my two projects to make this easier. But I totally understand the desire to separate them.